# RAID 1+0 and varying sized disks

Tags: raid

I am setting up a RAID 1+0 with 8 drives with the following:

- 2x 300GB (15K RPM)
- 6x 600GB (15K RPM)
- PERC H730 controller

I'm a bit confused what my total usable disk space would come out as. Would it be ~1200GB?

Also, is there any RAID reason the seller would specifically recommend varied sizes (which they did) as opposed to all the same sizes?

Comment: I would use the two smaller drives mirrored for the OS, the 6 remaining drives in a RAID 10.  If you did that, you'd have a RAID 1 with 300GB, and a RAID 10 with 1800GB.  I would be quite surprised if they were recommending you put varied disk sizes in a single RAID array.

Comment: Don't? Is there any reason you won't want to go with equally-sized drives?

Comment: @Zeno, Does the system you are looking at support UEFI?  If Dell built you a system with 8x600GB drives and you put those all into a single RAID10, you wouldn't be able to boot from that volume unless you have UEFI.  I haven't ordered a system from Dell in about 9 months, but really seemed to hide away the UEFI option, and really liked promoting a set of drives for the OS, and separate for the DATA volume.  That way you can have a bootable system, that doesn't require UEFI.

Comment: @Zoredache Ah, looks like it does: https://qrl.dell.com/Files/en-us/Html/Manuals/R630/Choosing%20the%20System%20Boot%20Mode=GUID-12C950B3-B0EF-4089-867E-89277DB2DA6A=3=en-us=.html

Comment: Not sure why Dell wouldn't let you build a system with 8x600GB drives.  configure.us.dell.com seems to show that as a valid configuration for a R630.  You going through a VAR or something?  Could just be the rep you are working with isn't actually paying attention to what you are asking for.  Sometimes you need to be quiet forceful to get them to pay attention and spec things out the correct way.

Comment: @Zoredache Going through a Dell Enterprise Product Specialist, but yeah... guess I'll just try clarifying again

Comment: They expect you to use 2 disks for OS. But with modern RAID controllers, you can make a single array of disks and carve them into right-sized logical volumes (virtual disks)

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this from being an X-Y problem, let's address the real issue:

The Dell configurator won't allow you to spec equal sized disks for your RAID 1+0.

They expect you to use 2 disks for OS. But with modern RAID controllers, you can make a single array of disks and carve them into right-sized logical volumes (virtual disks).

So make a big array of all disks and make a small virtual disk for the OS; e.g. 200GB. Then make another virtual disk for your data drives. These show up as discreet block devices in the OS.